# Chrome extension that can lock website for privacy

Tags: chrome, browser-extension

I am looking for a privacy oriented chrome extension that locks websites. Given a list of websites, it should be able to do:

1. Ask for password when someone opens the website for the first time.
2. Should have a global lock button, clicking on which it locks all the opened websites (that is listed)

Is there any such chrome extension like that?

Comment: Hello, define "lock", please. What should happen exactly if you enter a locked website?

Comment: Here,lock simply means when someone tries to open the site/page the extension will ask for the password

Comment: What if the extension gets removed or a different browser is used.

Comment: I think you need a standalone program that will block it for all browsers and cant itself be removed.